# Java newbie: cutting a string off?

Tags: java, string

I'm new to programming (taking a class) and I'm not sure how to accomplish this one task.

"Ignoring case, find the last occurrence of an ‘a’ in the input and remove all of the characters following it. In the case where there are no ‘a’s in the word, remove all but the first two characters (reminder: do not use if statements or loops). At the end of the now truncated word, add a number that is the percentage that the length of the truncated word is of the length of the original word; this percentage should be rounded to the closest integer value."

I'll be fine with the percentage part, but I'm not sure how to do the first part.

1. How do I remove only after the last occurrence of 'a'?
2. If there is no 'a' how do I cut it off after the first two letters without using an if statement?

I'm assuming its to be done using string manipulation and various substrings, but I'm not sure how the criteria for the substrings should be made.

Remember, Java newbie! I don't know a lot of fancy coding techniques yet.

Thank you!

Comment: `String#indexOf`, `String#subString` and probably `Math.min` as well...

Comment: Can a be the first letter in the word?

Comment: It doesn't say it can't be, so if the word was Apple, I suppose it would be right to cut it of after the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the last occurence of 'a' or 'A' you can use...

```
int index = Math.max(str.lastIndexOf('a'),str.lastIndexOf('A'));
index = (index==-1)?Math.min(2,str.length()):index+1;
```

Once you get the index you can use the following to remove the characters after it...

```
str.substring(0,index);
```

Comment: This will fail if a is the first character in the string, but is still a good solution, and it is probably the one your teacher is looking for.

Comment: I tried this method, and when I put in the word "sweater", the output was simply "ter" instead of the rest before the "ter". 
Should it be str.substring(0,index+1); ?

Comment: Also, any ideas on how to do the second option (return just the first two letters if no 'a' is present?

Comment: Ah yes sorry ... I misread and gave you the code for removing everything upto that point ... yes it should be str.substring(0,index+1);

Comment: The above would also cut off after the first two letters in case there is no 'A' because lastIndexOf would return -1 for str.substring('a') and str.substring('A') and Math.max(1,-1,-1) would give 1 thus effectively cutting off everything after the first two letters.

Comment: Hmm, it gives me an error when I try to put 3 arguments in to the Math.max. Would I have to store that max as a separate variable and do another max for it and 1?

Comment: As pointed out lightice11 this code will fail if 'a' is the first character of the input ... gknicker 's answer works for all cases by using a conditional statement.

Comment: Wow I made a lot of mistakes .... corrected and tested ... works for all cases now ....

Answer (score 3):

- [`String#toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) - remove all case from the `String`
- [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) will tell you where the last occurrence of the specified `String` occurs, will return `-1` if there is no occurrence, this is important.
- [`String#subString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) will allow you to generate a new `String` based on a sub element of the current `String`
- [`Math#max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)), [`Math#min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int))

Answer (score 2):

Given `String input`, consider the following as a possible starting point:

```
    int indexOfSmallA = input.lastIndexOf('a');
    int indexOfBigA = input.lastIndexOf('A');
    int beginIndex = Math.max(indexOfSmallA, indexOfBigA);
    // if not found, begin at 2 or end of input, else begin after last 'a'
    beginIndex = (beginIndex == -1) ? Math.min(2, input.length()) : beginIndex + 1;
    String result = input.substring(beginIndex);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Now using ternary operator instead. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: I would still consider that a "if-else" albeit a short handed version, but's me

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not entirely sure what the "beginIndex" part and beyond mean... I'm good with the first part and things that have an "a" in them work fine with that, but I'm still lost after that.